# php-di how to access container definitions

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

i have some config file which return array of key-value

```php
return [
    'my_key' => 'my value',
];
```

i have added it to the php-di container as definition

```php
$builder->addDefinitions(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config.php');
$container = $builder->build();
```

question is how to access data from the config file inside some method of the class which is used inside di container ?

lets say i have some classes

```php
class App
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router, Request $request)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->router->doSmth();
    }
}

class Router
{
    public function doSmth()
    {
       // how to access here to the config.php data to receive 'my value'
    }
}
```

so when i call

```
$container->get('\Core\App');
```

everything starts but i have no idea how to access the definitions data inside the methods of the registered classes because i dont have container instance inside the container itself to call smth like

```
$container->get('my_key'); // return 'my value'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `App` class `__constructor` the parameters are injected. Just like those, you can inject the configuration there.

Your refer to the container by type hinting the `ContainerInterface` class. As mentioned in the [issue on github](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge/issues/19#issuecomment-375904463) your code for `App` will look like:

```php
class App
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router, Request $request, ContainerInterface $c)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->router->doSmth($c->get('my_key'));
    }
}

class Router
{
    public function doSmth($my_key)
    {
       // You now have access to that particular key from the settings
    }
}
```

This will make your `Router` dependent on getting the config by the `doSmth()` function.

---

Depending on your usage of the `Router` class, you might want to loose that dependency on calling `doSmth($my_key)` with that config parameter. Since in the `App` class you are injecting the `Router` class, it means you can also profit from injection in the `Router` class itself. Just like how you `__construct` your `App` class, you can also do that with your `Router` class.

*Doing this from the top of my head now, but this should work if I am not mistaken...*

Your code will look like this:

```php
class App
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router, Request $request)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->router->doSmth();
    }
}

class Router
{
    private $some_setting;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $c)
    {
       $this->some_setting = $c->get('my_key');
    }

    public function doSmth()
    {
       // You now have access to $this->some_setting
    }
}
```

---

Note that the `my_key` key comes directly from the PHP-DI container definitions if for example a `settings.php` file with an array is added as definitions. More about definitions [here](http://php-di.org/doc/definition-overriding.html). As I am combining this myself with the Slim framework, I usually prepend my keys in `settings.php` with `settings.` like for example `setting.my_key`. However there are probably cleaner solutions available if making use of the ability to [extends definitions](http://php-di.org/doc/definition-overriding.html#extending-definitions).

Comment: TY for your fast answer. yesterday i kept trying and found this magic. it was just enough  to add in constructor signature reference to the **Psr\Container\ContainerInterface** just like you show here in the answer and magic appears :) 

have another question you address in your example to **'settings.my_key'**. it is possible to make definitions "named" ? or this is just good practice to name array keys in this way (dot separated) for DI container ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "named" definitions. Settings are somehow converted to the dot key notation when added as array definition. For me this was good enough, so I stopped bothering researching other solutions ;)

Comment: strange, it doesnt work on my side. if im trying by filename **No entry or class found for 'routes.hello'**, with just settings doesn't work as well **No entry or class found for 'settings.hello'**, only when i call just "hello" **$c->get('hello')** it does work. Only if i name array key as **settings.hello** then i can access it as "settings.hello"

Comment: @Eugene Ah, I am terrible sorry! Totally forgot about that part. My key in my `settings.php` array is indeed `settings.my_key`. With that I followed how PHP-DI documented the configuration of Slim (http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/slim.html#configuring-slim). I also did not want to pollute the container root keys with setting keys (unless clearly a setting, thus `settings.` prepended. Now that I read more about definitions, you could probably created a cleaner way for your setting definitions (maybe using this http://php-di.org/doc/definition-overriding.html#arrays)

Comment: I edited my answer to make the part about where the key comes from a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure what to inject in your objects: http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#autowired-objects

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the value, I think you can just use `DI\get`.

```
public function doSmth() {
    echo DI\get('my_key');
}
```

From here: http://php-di.org/doc/environments.html

Comment: This will not work, `DI\get()` should only be used in the configuration.